# use variable created remotely in local script

Tags: bash, shell-script, rhel

i've this script:

```
#!/bin/bash
ssh server bash -c "'
if [[ "\$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
PRINT="N"
echo \${PRINT}
else
PRINT="Y"
echo \${PRINT}
fi
'"
echo $PRINT
```

but $PRINT locally is empty, how can i pass this variable by remote to locally?

Thanks!

Comment: Is this an example, or: is there a real command before the $? checking, or are you intending to check the success of the ssh command?

Comment: I looks like you're not escaping your internal double-quotes. Is that intentional?

Answer (score 0):

Remove the shelling of another bash process on the remote server and then read the complete command output into a variable (in this case resp)

```
#!/bin/bash
resp=$(ssh server '
if [[ "\$?" -ne "0" ]]; then
PRINT="N"
echo \${PRINT}
else
PRINT="Y"
echo \${PRINT}
fi')

echo $resp
```

Comment: Hi, i cant use this way, because the ssh connection have a lot of command: